# Restkit SSL tutorial

Tags: https, restkit

I try to use restkit with SSL but it does not work.
I have the following exception:

Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo=0xc465d70

I read the documentation and post question on the forum but no answer...

- I have added the security framework
- I have tried to set the RESTKIT_SSL_VALIDATION directive... but it is not clear for me how to set this directive :
  a. in the project using restkit ?
  b. or in restkit project itself ?
  c. Menu in XCode to set this directive ?

The Restkit question I have posted on the Restkit forum: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/restkit/8BW_1L2btIA

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a kind of network problem, just have a try with following steps :-

-Try restarting the iMac/MacBook

-Try restarting the internet router

-Try using a totally different internet connection (such as one at a friends house, or an internet café)

In addition let's try by setting disableCertificateValidation = YES. in your RKClient.